# What is the difference between strtol and strtoul?

Tags: c, strtol, c-standard-library

I met some unexcepted result of `strtol` in c

Here is the sample program.

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>    
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    printf("%x\n", strtol("0xfffff70A", NULL, 0));
    return 0;
}
```

and the output of this simple program is

```
0x7fffffff
```

rather than `0xfffff70A`. 
And if I use `strtoul`, the result is exactly `0xfffff70a`.
I am using a 32-bit machine, and I wonder what happens.
PS. I am using gcc 4.7.2

Comment: Set `errno` to `0` before calling `strtol` or `strtoul` and check it afterwards. Do not use the value if `errno` has a different value.

Comment: Nice question, by the way: Next to minimal code example, input, observed output, expected output. +1 for making this so easy to answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From 7.22.1.4 paragraph 8 (of [the N1570 draft of the 2011 edition of the standard](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf)):

> If the correct value is outside the range of representable values, `LONG_MIN`, `LONG_MAX`, `LLONG_MIN`,
>   `LLONG_MAX`, `ULONG_MAX`, or `ULLONG_MAX` is returned (according to the return type and sign of the value, if any), and the value of the macro `ERANGE` is stored in errno.

Since the correct value of your input string is too large for the type, you get `LONG_MAX`, and `errno` is set to `ERANGE`.

Whenever one of the `strto(u)l(l)` functions returns one of the `TYPE_MAX` or `TYPE_MIN` values, you need to check `errno` to find out whether it's a correct result, or your input was out-of-range.

Comment: Damn, I was *just* about to paste the same. :-D @PascalCuoq: Behaviour of the `strto...` functions is very well-defined even in case of overflows. That's what makes them superior to e.g. `*scanf()` functions for parsing numerical input.

Comment: Can you also specify from where you're quoting?

Comment: @OlafDietsche: That would be ISO/IEC 9899 (the C language standard).

Comment: @DevSolar Not everybody knows that :-)

Comment: In contrast, why can `(int)strtoul("-2",NULL,0)` return the "correct" value?

Comment: @user1668903 From paragraph 5: "If the subject sequence begins with a minus sign, the value resulting from the conversion is negated (in the return type)." The `"2"` part of the input is parsed as the value 2 of type `unsigned long`. Then that value is negated, that makes it `ULONG_MAX + 1 - 2`, (the mathematical result is reduce modulo `ULONG_MAX + 1` to obtain a value in the range `[0, ULONG_MAX]`). Then that is converted to `int` in an implementation-defined manner (assuming `ULONG_MAX > INT_MAX`). Usually, the least significant bits are just reinterpreted, and in two's complement that's -2

Comment: @DevSolar You are referring to a mistake that was in my answer for only two minutes! I remembered and fixed it immediately. You are right, functions of this family have well-defined behavior as long as they are passed a well-formed string.

Comment: @PascalCuoq: I was only here for a minute or so. ;-) Actually the `strto*()` functions are well-defined even for non-well-formed string. Nevermind, I think this was answered to satisfaction. ;-)

Comment: @DevSolar Here is a use of `strtol()` that results in undefined behavior. The undefined behavior is caused by `s` not being a well-formed string. http://ideone.com/Qs2i7n

Comment: @PascalCuoq: Ah... OK, *that* kind of non-well-formed-ness. ;-) I bow out of the discussion, you found a way to break the function. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You're running into overflow of the `long` type, which is signed.

You probably should use:

```
print("%lx\n", strtoul("0xfffff70a", NULL, 0));
                    ^
                    |
                 important!
```

instead, note the 'u' for "unsigned" (see [manual page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strtoul)).

Also note that you can't print an `unsigned long` with plain `%x`, you need to qualify it as being bigger than `int`.

Answer (score 0):

Your architecture has a 32-bit `long` type. `0xfffff70A` is not representable as a signed 32-bit `long`. `errno` should have been set to `ERANGE`.

In 2's complement, representable values for 32-bit signed integers range from `-0x80000000` to `0x7fffffff`.